# Как влияет опция "In Database Archiving" на индексы и производительность?

Tags: sql, oracle, производительность, oracle12c, индексация

В Oracle 12c есть опция, позволяющая архивировать старые данные в той же таблице без создания новых таблиц - *In Database Archiving*. Ее просто использовать, но есть вопрос про производительность и индексы.

Как работают индексы в особенности уникальные индексы?
Можно ли добавить такое значение в колонку, которая должна быть уникальной?

Например, запись с уникальным значением `1` колонки `col NUMBER` заархивирована. Что будет, если добавить запись с `col = 1`, будут ли учитываться заархивированные данные? Если да, значит архивация и не сильно помогает в улучшении производительности, а если нет, то при выборке из всех данных (`visibility = all`) нарушается уникальность поля.

Как это все работает?

Comment: Вроде некоторые вещи это [две минуты проверить](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=600900bb78da4eb1c4d5dadd5455f90a). Не могли бы вы конкретизировать вопрос?

Comment: Если учитываются заархивированные, значит по скорости выборке и по записи нет выигрыша. Эта фича только ради того чтобы скрыть ненужные данные. Получается бесполезная фича?

Comment: Чтобы выиграть по скорости, нужно все таки создавать отдельную таблицу/ схему/бд

Comment: Не совсем помятно, что вы хотите добится. Почему по скорости выборке и по записи нет выигрыша?  _чтобы скрыть ненужные данные_, ненужные данные обычно удаляются.  _Получается бесполезная фича_, смотря для чего ее использовать, если бы она была бы совсем никому не нужна, ее бы не ввели.

Comment: Какой выигрыш по спорости выборки и записи новых данных

Comment: Зависит от того, что вы делаете, структуры таблиц и многого другого.

Comment: Как работает индексирование FULL SCAN

Comment: А что такое _индексирование FULL SCAN_? Полное чтение чего?

Comment: У меня такое чуство, что вам нужно партиционирование таблиц с локальными индексами. Не  так ли?

Comment: Есть таблица с 10 миллионами строк, если заархивировать 9 млн строк, насколько увеличится скорость выполнения запросов, допустим есть разные запросы для которых есть индексы а есть и без индексов

Comment: Полное сканирование таблицы - это сканирование, выполненное в базе данных, где каждая строка таблицы читается в последовательном порядке, а обнаруженные столбцы проверяются на действительность условия. Википедия

Comment: Думаю производительность не улучшится. Эта фича не вводилась с целью - улучшить производительность. _Как работает индексирование FULL SCAN_, если вы имеете ввиду полное сканирование таблицы, то индексы здесь не причём, они вообще не читаются.

Comment: Если не для улучшения производительности тогда для чего эта фича вводилась?

Comment: Для удобства. Она заменяет ранее применявшиеся решение  со столбцом deleted=1 и включение этого столбца в условие выборки во всех запросах. А почему вы решили, что она для улучшения производительности? В документации стоит буквально - _без потери производительности_, но не для ее улучшения.

Comment: Вы так и не описали вашу задачу. Если вам интересна производительность без удаления  данных, то вам партиционирование нужно. А то получается, чтобы забить гвоздь вы взяли отвёртку и спрашиваете - как ею решить задачу, и зачем она тогда нужна, если ею гвоздь забить нельзя.

Comment: Спасибо, подумаю про партицирование. Вообще вопрос был про как помогает в производительности эта фича, вы ответили, ни как. Так и думал. Буду искать дальше

Comment: Хорошо, давайте поступим так: я отвечу на вопрос с учётом 10 млн./9 млн в архиве. Ну это чтобы дискусия за зря не пропала, а там посмотрим. Про  партицирование, это пока только совет, в какую сторону смотреть. Для конкретного решения, нужно знать конкретную структуру таблиц/индексов и условий филтров в приложении.

Comment: Да, давайте, вопрос был про перформанс, вы мне на него ответили.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

О новой опции [In Database Archiving](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-5A76B6CE-C96D-49EE-9A89-0A2CB993A933.htm#VLDBG14154) в документации к версии 12.1:

> With In-Database Archiving you can store more data for a longer period of time within a single database, without compromising application performance.

Можно хранить больше данных в течение более длительного периода времени в самой таблице *без ухудшения производительности* запросов.
Заметьте, что *об улучшении производительности* в документации не упоминается.

> To manage In-Database Archiving for a table, you must enable ROW ARCHIVAL for the table and manipulate the ORA_ARCHIVE_STATE hidden column of the table.

Для достижения этого, в таблице будет создана скрытая символьная колонка (скрытые (*hiden*) колонки были также введены в этой версии) `ORA_ARCHIVE_STATE` со значением по умолчанию `'0'=active`, которой можно присвоить значение `'1'=archived`, чтобы сделать запись невидимой для запросов без явного указания этого в условии самого запроса.

Другими словами, фильтрация по состоянию архивирования записей, по сути является обычным предикатом, который будет добавлен неявно при выполнении запроса, и ожидать, что оптимизатор "магическим образом" обойдёт архивированные записи при чтении, не следует. На *индексы архивирование записей никак не влияет*.

---

Для подтверждения вышесказанного, посмотрим воспроизводимый пример:

```
create table t (x int unique, y int) row archival
/
insert /*+ append */ into t
    select rownum, rownum from dual connect by level<=1e5
/
100,000 rows inserted.
commit;
 
update t set ora_archive_state='1' where x<=99999
/
99,999 rows updated.
commit;

select t.*, ora_archive_state from t 
/
         X          Y ORA_ARCHIVE_STATE       
---------- ---------- ------------------------
    100000     100000 0                       

insert into t values (1, 1)
/
Error report -
ORA-00001: unique constraint (DB.SYS_C0011003) violated
```

Пока статистика не собрана, оптимизатор считает, что запрос вернёт 100K записей:

```
SQL> set autotrace trace
SQL> select t.* from t

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |   100K|  1171K|    69   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |   100K|  1171K|    69   (2)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("T"."ORA_ARCHIVE_STATE"='0')
```

После сбора статистики, она будет включать в себя архивированные записи:

```
SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats (user, upper ('t'), cascade=>true)
SQL> select  num_rows from user_tables where table_name = 'T';

TABLE_NAME         NUM_ROWS
---------------- ----------
T                    100000

SQL> select table_name, index_name, num_rows from user_indexes where table_name = 'T';

TABLE_NAME       INDEX_NAME         NUM_ROWS
---------------- ---------------- ----------
T                SYS_C0011003         100000

SQL> select column_name, num_distinct, low_value, high_value from dba_tab_col_statistics
where table_name = 'T';

COLUMN_NAME       NUM_DISTINCT LOW_VALUE  HIGH_VALUE
----------------- ------------ ---------- ----------
ORA_ARCHIVE_STATE            2 30         31
```

Теперь оптимизатор знает, что запрос вернёт только одну запись, но это не делает выборку эффективней - по прежнему полное сканирование таблицы:

```
SQL> select t.* from t
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |    12 |    69   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |     1 |    12 |    69   (2)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   1 - filter("T"."ORA_ARCHIVE_STATE"='0')
```